# How to do a search a data in my firebase database [Android]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to do a "search bar" with a editText , the goal of the application is a user enter a word and after I check with my firebase database if its word exist and I display it or not in a text view .

My data base : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5ydr.png)

and my code (i want to compare the input of user and the result of the field "nomP") :

```js
public class recherche extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference bdd_Produit;
    List<Produit> lesP;
    EditText edtRecherche;
    TextView txtResultat;
    Button btnCherche;
    Button acc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recherche);
        edtRecherche = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtRecherche);
        btnCherche = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCherche);
        acc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAcc);

        bdd_Produit = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("produit");

        acc.setText("Accueil");
        btnCherche.setText("valide");

        //initialisation var
        lesP = new ArrayList<>();

        btnCherche.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            bdd_Produit.orderByChild("nomP").equalTo(edtRecherche.getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                    new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //data will be available on dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            txtResultat.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
        }
    });

    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help and if you need other information that I forgot i'm here ! :)

Comment: where is the question, what you need exactly

Comment: I need search the input of user in my data base and if the input exist i want to display it in a textview

Answer (score 0):

you need to creat your model class for the Produit then

```
bdd_Produit.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edtRecherche.getText())){
                if (snapshot.getValue(Produit.class).getNomP().equals(edtRecherche.getText().toString()))
                    //produit founded
                else
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```